# A Calabi-Yau threefold under different complex structures

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let's say, we have a Calabi--Yau threefold $X$ (a three dimensional non-singular complex variety whose canonical bundle $K_X$ is trivial or equivalently a non-singular complex variety with a nowhere vanishing holomorphic $(3,0)$--form).

Question: For a different complex structure, can we still find a no-where vanishing $(3,0)$-form which makes $X$ a Calabi-Yau threefold? If so, why?

Note: I am trying to understand the existence of so-called "the vacuum line bundle" on the moduli space of complex structures of a Calabi-Yau threefold.

Comment: I don’t know whether this is possible for arbitrary deformations of the manifold, but it’s true for small (or even “most”) deformations by the Hodge numbers of small deformations of compact Kahler manifolds being constant. That implies the canonical bundles of neighboring manifolds have a nonzero holomorphic  section. It’ll be parallel with respect to a Ricci flat metric, so being nonzero in one point implies being nonzero everywhere so it trivializes the canonical bundle of the neighbor, which is then Calabi-Yau.

Comment: @DenizGenlik What does "a different complex structure" mean? What is parametrizing the complex structures? As Gunnar points out, small deformations of Calabi--Yau (in the sense of Kähler manifolds with trivial canonical bundle) remain Calabi--Yau.

Comment: Zhiqin Lu, a student of Tian, has done a lot of work on Calabi--Yau manifolds and their moduli (at least 20 years ago), especially Calabi--Yau threefolds

Comment: If I recall correctly, you don't even need $X$ to be smooth for small deformations to remain Calabi--Yau, $X$ can have canonical singularities, I believe.